# Connecting to a school network

Tags: wifi, wireless

I could connect to the Raspberry Pi with my Wi-Fi dongle to my home network easily, but I couldn't connect to the university network which is public. Is there any change in configuration  setup file (/etc/network/intertfaces)
My file consists of:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface etho inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "myssid"
        wpa-psk "pwd"
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll <s>need</s> want `/etc/network/interfaces`. You'll have to use `wpa_supplicant` in that case. It'll make your life easier.

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Then, in your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file, simply add your WiFi configuration(s). I'm sure it's easy to follow.

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="Superbly secure WPA home network"
    psk="correctHorseBatt3ry5taple42"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
}

network={
        ssid="Horribly insecure open school network"
        key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Take note that the SSID is **case-sensitive**.

Answer (score 1):

afaik you don't need the `/etc/network/interfaces` for connecting to open wifi hotspots.

All you need is a few programs from `wireless-tools`:

Scan for access points: `iwlist wlan0 scan`

Now get the ESSID for the access point you want to connect to

Connect to it: `ifconfig wlan0 essid ap_name`

and get dhcp data(ip, dns, etc.): `dhclient wlan0`

now you should be connected. You may have to adjust `wlan0` to the name of your adaptor.

Beware that most schools/universities have a MAC access filter and you maybe won't be able to get internet connection.

EDIT:
If you try to connect to an university wifi, maybe they have 802.1x auth, then try [this](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/wpa_supplicant#802-1X-Netzwerke) (it's german, but not difficult to understand, you may try Google Translator ;) )